# MultiAutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter (BaseAdapter)

Tags: android, filter, autocompletetextview

I am using a `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` and setting my own custom adapter (BaseAdapter) on it. But every time I write something in MultiAutoCompleteTextView, the constraint in the `performFiltering` method always gets null value for every character I write.

Here is my code for the BaseAdapter class:

```
public class ListItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    ArrayList<ListItem> listItems;
    ArrayList<ListItem> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
    private Filter filter = new CustomFilter();
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListItemAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);

        title.setText(listItems.get(position).getTitle());
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    private class CustomFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            suggestions.clear();

            Log.d("FILTERRES", ""+listItems.size() + ", " + constraint);

            if(listItems != null && constraint != null) {
                for(int i=0 ; i<listItems.size(); i++) {
                    if(listItems.get(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        suggestions.add(listItems.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = suggestions;
            results.count = suggestions.size();
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if(results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am setting the adapter to MultiAutoCompleteTextView:

```
MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.auto);
ListItemAdapter adapter = new ListItemAdapter(items, this);
textView.setThreshold(1);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**:
I changed my `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` to `AutoCompleteTextView` and now it is working, does anyone know how to make it work for MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `setTokenizer()` to your `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` in order to get it work.

You can use -

```
 textView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

Even you can set your own custom tokenizer if you have any special requirements else you can use `CommaTokenizer` which appends comma(,) everytime you select any option from the dropdown.